# Jenkins docker workflow plugin executes without PATH

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

I'm having issues running a shell command in a Docker container with the Jenkins declarative pipeline. using the docker workflow plugin.  It seems that it can't find the command 'cat', suggesting a path issue.   I have limited the task to a simple task (env shell command) in a very simple image (alpine) and verified that /bin/cat works.   What is my mistake/misunderstanding?

Updated:  I am including the entire command that Jenkins generates.   I didn't add all these extra arguments, for some reason Jenkins seems to inject them outside my control.

```
$ docker run -t -d -u 496:493 -w /jenkins/workspace/project-pipeline@2 -v /jenkins/workspace/project-pipeline@2:/jenkins/workspace/project-pipeline@2:rw -v /jenkins/workspace/project-pipeline@2@tmp:/jenkins/workspace/project@2@tmp:rw -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** --entrypoint cat alpine
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'alpine'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: Container command 'cat' not found or does not exist..
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.run(DockerClient.java:125)
```

And here is my pipeline stage:

```
stage("test") {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'alpine'
      label 'docker-enabled'
    }
  }
  steps {
    sh 'env'
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are running on linux , then what is the result of  `cat /etc/issue`   ?

Comment: try running `echo $PATH` to see what the path is. If the path isn't correctly set.
`docker run --name alp -dt alpine cat` and `docker exec alp sh -c "env"` gives me:
`HOSTNAME=a2b6eeb0788a
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
`

Comment: This is Jenkins-specific failure.   Cat is on the execution path when I run from command line.   Requested output - 
`$ docker run -id --entrypoint cat alpine 3719b36a40ecc36eada4674def442b2140f22ed2aec030390acd2ef838763722
    $ docker exec 3719 cat /etc/issue 
     Welcome to Alpine Linux 3.4
    Kernel \r on an \m (\l)`

Comment: In all of the `-e *****` that were censored out, did any of them happen to be setting the PATH?

Comment: That's a good theory, but I don't know because the Jenkins Docker Workflow plugin is setting and censoring those values.   But it would be crazy if the plugin was replacing the entrypoint with 'cat' and then removing /bin from the path.   Might be worth a look in the source code.